# woocommerce api 401 error on Xcode8 Request

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, xcode8, woocommerce-rest-api

While trying to link the woo-commerce api's generated on xcode8 I am getting error 401 (on googleing a bit found its authentication error) however the same api link and the keys seem to work fine on browser.
Adding the code snip of xcode for reference.

```
let urlString = "https://serverUrl.com"

func downloadJsonWithURl(){

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
    //keys for authentication
    request.addValue("A KEY", forHTTPHeaderField: "Consumer-key")
    request.addValue("A SECRET", forHTTPHeaderField: "Secret-key")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary 
            print (jsonObj as Any)
        }
    })       .resume()
}
```

Comment: This looks like Swift code: why tagging it PHP?

Answer (score 0):

after a bit poking . i got fix this.
just modify the  .plist file
add App Transport Security Settings and within that Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content  and  Allow Arbitrary Loads to YES.

[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdQUQ.png)